# WPF - ItemsControl Fires Setter and Overrides Null Value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism

I'm working in MVVM using Prism and I'm struggling to bind a `TimeEditor` to a nullable `TimeSpan`. Every time I `TwoWay` bind to my value, it overrides the null value and changes it to `00:00:00`. As soon as I change it to `OneWay`, it works fine and keeps the `null` value.

XAML

```
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompanyHoursList, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="0 3" BorderBrush="#444" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Padding="0 0 0 5">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Day}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                <c1:C1TimeEditor Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding Path=CloseTime, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowNull="True"></c1:C1TimeEditor>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

CompanyHours.cs

```
 public class CompanyOperationHours : BindableBase
    {
        private DayOfWeek _day;
        private TimeSpan? _openTime;
        private TimeSpan? _closeTime;

        public DayOfWeek Day
        {
            get { return _day; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _day, value);
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan? OpenTime
        {
            get { return _openTime; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _openTime, value);
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan? CloseTime
        {
            get { return _closeTime; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _closeTime, value);
            }
        }

        public CompanyOperationHours(DayOfWeek day)
        {
            Day = day;
        }
  }
```

This is driving me absolutely nuts and would love if anyone could provide some insight. If I pull the TimeEditor out of the ItemsControl and put it in a random place, bind it to the specific item in the list and that same property, it works fine. It's only when I add it to the `ItemsControl` and `TwoWay` bind it that it changes the `null` value and displays `12:00:00 AM` instead of null.

Comment: Is `C1TimeEditor` a custom control? Perhaps it is changing the value and that's what needs to be debugged. The code you provided looks fine and sounds like the control itself is misbehaving.

Comment: @TyCobb ```C1TimeEditor``` is a ComponentOne control.

Comment: @TyCobb Also, I don't think it's the ```TimeEditor``` because it works fine when it isn't in the ```ItemsControl```.

Comment: Weird. I'm just going to throw the kitchen sink at it and say try setting your ItemsSource to TwoWay instead of OneWay. I really don't know other than maybe you're in a different scope and maybe the DataContext isn't your CompanyOperationHours

Comment: @TyCobb haha I've been banging my head against this for hours now. Unfortunately, it's not the DataContext, because the TextBlock above it displays the proper thing. I also have tried binding a Textblock to this property and it displays the proper thing. It's something totally weird.

Comment: Okay last really out-of-the-park suggestion before I slowly back away, but if AllowNull is false by default, you may want to reorder it so it gets set to true first before you set the Value.